# Python error: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: xml, sqlite, python-2.6, elementtree, eol

## Some background information

I am using SQLite to access a database and retrieve the desired information. I'm using ElementTree in Python version 2.6 to create an XML file with that information.

## Code

Here is the code I'm using to create an XML file from the database schema. I've denoted the location the error occurs with a comment.

```
 import sqlite3
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

 db = sqlite3.connect("dataload.db")
 root = ET.Element("databaseConfiguration")


 software_attributes =  ["id", "functionalDesignationHardware", "hwfin", "identname", "partnumber",
                         "repfin", "targetHardwareID"]

 software = db.cursor().execute("SELECT %s from SOFTWARE_" % ", ".join([i + "_" for i in software_attributes]))
 software_Data = software.fetchall()
 for sw in software_Data:
     sw_node = ET.SubElement(root, "Software")
     for i in range(1, len(software_attributes)):
         sw_node.set(software_attributes[i], str(sw[i]))


 target_attributes = ["id", "functionalDesignationSoftware", "installscriptpathname", "ata", "status",
                      "swfin", "targetOSFC", "timestamp"]


 tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

 from xml.dom import minidom
 print minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent = "   ")

 ## The error pops up at this line (when trying to generate the XML) ##
 tree.write("New_Database.xml)
```

## Question

How do I fix this error? I've seen some other questions where quotes had to be added or edited - do I need to do something similar, and how?

Comment: At first glance, it looks ok except for the missing close quote on the filename.  What does the error message say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice before that you had put the error message (EOL while scanning string literal) in the title.  So, what I thought was a typo in your post is really the error.  Add the closing quote to your string.

Comment: Omg that might be it. Unfortunately I can't actually check if that's the case since everything is on my work computer. I'm gonna hope that's the error since it's super simple instead of just a copy/paste error. I'll know by Monday...hopefully I don't get any new errors. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely was the error. I am derp. Thanks for un-derping my code

Comment: Happens to all of us.  Glad I could help.